# Xcode- Importing Objective C files into a C file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

If I create a c file and add this to the top.

```
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>
```

I get a bunch of strange errors. This is the case if I import any objective C file. I have seen nothing about this in other questions/answers. Everyone seems to suggest that C and Objective C work seamlessly together!

```
gl.h
Unknown type name 'GLenum'; did you mean 'enum'?

GLKNamedEffect.h
Expected identifier or '('
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you rename your c file from `something.c` to `something.m`, you should be able to use:

```
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>
```

within your file. Now, if you do that, the resulting file will be an Objective-C file and will need an Objective-C compiler to be compiled, hence the need to specify the `.m` extension.

In other words, Objective-C is a language built on top of C. So you "mix" their syntaxes, so to speak but only the Objective-C compiler will be able to compile the mix. The C compiler will know nothing about ObjC.

By changing the extension of your file, you are in a way choosing the compiler, and you can have a "plain C" file which imports an Objective-C header and calls into some Objective-C library.

Comment: Objective-C is a **superset** of C, so you can use C in an Objective-C file, but not necessarily the other way around.

Comment: From the OP - `Everyone seems to suggest that C and Objective C work seamlessly together!` - they are not seamless, hence my much abbreviated answer

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It all makes complete sense now.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: your response was totally correct, of course. I have preferred to elaborate more so that the topic could possibly become clearer to the asker.

Comment: My terseness is not always a virtue :)

Answer (score 1):

C isn't objective-c and so, cannot import objective-c source or include files. (In other words, what you have been told is false)