# SpriteKit and C file ( not objective_C file )

Tags: objective-c, c, swift, sprite-kit

How do you call Spritekit functions/variables inside a C file ( .h .c ) ? not objective_C file ( .h .m )

Thank you for your help

Comment: Import your C header file in the bridging file, and call your C code in .swift file as you are doing with Obj-C code.

Comment: @Whirlwind I think he is looking to go the other way,  using spritekit inside C

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Oh, you are right. I wonder what is the purpose of doing something like that...

Comment: Perhaps OP does not know that Objective C is a strict superset of C  (Basically C with object oriented programming)  To OP:  I am not sure if you can import objective C libraries into C,  I tried looking for an answer for you, and all I found was this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127124/xcode-importing-objective-c-files-into-a-c-file  which basically says no

Comment: I added tags, and upvoted your question (unlike the other two slackers here).